# How to access IoT Digital Twin Service

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-digital-twins

Azure has recently launched a new service called Digital twins. Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/digital-twins/. But in the link I can only get to the "Learn more" page which doesn't have much information. There is nowhere to try  this product and it's not getting listed in the Azure portal product list or in the preview list to try. I am looking for a how-to doc or link on setting up this for virtual building as described in the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Public Preview Release of Azure Digital Twins is now live. Docs are available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/.

Comment: Much of the documentation and content has been continuously improved since the initial Public Preview launch in response to customer feedback and delight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the [introduction blog](https://blogs.microsoft.com/iot/2018/09/24/announcing-azure-digital-twins-create-digital-replicas-of-spaces-and-infrastructure-using-cloud-ai-and-iot/) states, the public preview will begin October 15, 2018: "Azure Digital Twins will be publicly available for customers to begin building solutions October 15th."